# return to input data in a function

Tags: python, function, loops

I want to rerun the input in the else case when the input is not valid, but I'm having trouble with this. Can someone help me?

```
    
    cType = input("criteria type (0 - minimization, 1 - maximization): ")
    tipo = float(cType)
    
    def get_tipo(value):
        if value == 0:
            print("minimization criterion")
        elif value == 1:
            print("maximization criterion")
        else:
            print("not valid value")
            return cType             
    
    e = get_tipo(tipo)
```

In case tipo is not equal to 0 or 1, I would like to repeat the process, but I don't know how to do it. The code just continues without respecting that condition

Comment: Put the conditionals inside a loop. This is not a difficult one. Easily searchable online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a while loop.

```
while True:
    cType = input("criteria type (0 - minimization, 1 - maximization): ")
    tipo = float(cType)
    if tipo in [0,1]:
        if tipo == 0:
            print("minimization criterion")
        elif tipo == 1:
            print("maximization criterion")
        break
    else:
        print("not valid value")
```